# Same product name with different price in different states

Tags: database-design, normalization

Consider the price of products in the table differs in each state. If the price varies in district I also have to mention it. How can I do this for more than 5 states?

```
product Name   Price  Wholeseller Price Retailer price   state     district
-------------|------|------------------|---------------|-----------|------
fan          |   6  |   12         |     18            | delhi      name1
wheels       |   10 |   17         |     27            | delhi      name1
biscuits     |   5  |   10         |     23            | delhi      name1
biscuits     |   6  |   11         |     24            | delhi      name2
fan          |   7  |   13         |     20            | karnataka  ...
wheels       |   9  |   16         |     26            | karnataka  ...
biscuits     |   5  |   12         |     25            | karnataka  ...
```

Image of table [here](http://i46.tinypic.com/abl6qr.png).

Here I'm repeating the product for each state. Is it a correct method? Should I make a separate table for states & districts or is there a need to normalize?

Comment: Yes, this structure can (and probably should) be normalized.

Comment: How can i normalize it

Comment: Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: please take a look at my normalized table(http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xc9bg9&s=6)..    can you please give me an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normalize your tables.  In third normal form (3NF) you tables would look like this:

[image]

Notice that this is different from your normalized table picture in two important respects:  First, states and districts should be separated into two tables so you don't repeat the state names.  Second, and more importantly, prices depend on district and product.  Therefore the price should be in the intersection table between district and product, not in the same table as states and districts.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Joel Brown  
**state** (st_id,st_name)  **district** (d_id,d_name,st_id)   
**price** (price_id,min_price,max_price,pid,d_id)  **product** (pid,p_name)
**dateUP** (date_id,date,price_id)  

Do i'm right now

Comment: @KumarHtabmas - Yes, looks good.